# How do i hide a button through the user pressing a button

Tags: ios, button, hide

My app is a quiz app and what i am trying to do is when the user selects an incorrect answer it will either stop running the quiz app and show a button for the user to go to the beginning. Or it will hide all the buttons and labels except the button to go back to the beginning. Which ever one is easier.

please let me know! I have tried things like `Button1.hidden = true/YES` but it doesn't hide the button

Thanks

```
@IBAction func Button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {

    if AnswerNumber == 0 {
        PickQuestion()
        LabelEnd.text = "Goodjob buddy"
    }    
    else {
        Hide()
        LabelEnd.text = "Unlucky pal"
        Again.hidden = false
        QuestionLabel.hidden = true 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

UILabel , UIButton are inherited from UIView. And UIView has a property 'isHidden'. So, If you do

```
someview.isHidden = true
```

this will work as a function and hide the view from layout!
Try again!

Comment: I tried it but it says UIButton has no member 'isHidden'

Comment: Really!? , please find isHidden or hidden property In UIView class .

Comment: Don't worry about it bro i have found a way, when user chooses the wrong answer it takes them to a different view controller. Thanks for your time bro!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like....

There will be `rootViewController` from where user start quiz.

So when user select incorrect answer then you can redirect user to `rootViewController` by calling `popToRootViewController:` method.

And you can also show an alert.

So you don't  need to hide or show any thing.:)

Comment: I just tried this code but it comes up with a Thread 1 Signal SIGABRT  let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! nrlPauseMenu1View
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Don't worry bro i found out a new way to do it, thanks for your answer though mate!